# Scrapy - How to scrape content generated with javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some classified ads on http://www.head-fi.org/f/6550/headphones-for-sale-trade

I created a spider which can scrape the titles, prices, descriptions, etc. It is working well but I can't figure out how the pagination works on that specific website. I believe it is being generated with javascript? Since the URL doesn't change.

This is my code to scraping the first page

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from headfi_headphones.items import HeadfiHeadphonesItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "headfiheadphones"
    allowed_domains = ["head-fi.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.head-fi.org/f/6550/headphones-for-sale-trade"]

    #rules = (
    #    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='tooltip']",)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    #)

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//tr[@class='thread']")
    items = []
    for title in titles:
        item = HeadfiHeadphonesItem()
        item["title"] = title.select("td[@class='thread-col']/div[@class='shazam']/div[@class='thumbnail_body']/a[@class='classified-title']/text()").extract()
        item["link"] = title.select("td[@class='thread-col']/div[@class='shazam']/div[@class='thumbnail_body']/a[@class='classified-title']/@href").extract()
        item["img"] = title.select("td[@class='thread-col']/div[@class='shazam']/div[@class='thumbnail']/a[@class='thumb']/img/@src").extract()
        item["saletype"] = title.select("td/strong/text()").extract()
        item["price"] = title.select("td/div[@class='price']/span[@class='ctx-price']/text()").extract()
        item["currency"] = title.select("td/div[@class='price']/span[@class='currency']/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

It returns something like this (I've included one entry)

```
{"img": ["http://cdn.head-fi.org/9/92/80x80px-ZC-9228072e_image.jpeg"], "title": ["Hifiman HE1000 Mint"], "saletype": ["For Sale"], "price": ["$2,000"], "currency": ["(USD)"], "link": ["/t/819200/hifiman-he1000-mint"]},
```

Is there a way to scrape through each page (1-80 or so) which is being populated on a table by what I assume is javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To properly parse Javascript you should consider using `selenium`. The package is available here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium.